# How to increase the font size of legend values in image.plot function in R programming?

Tags: r, plot, legend-properties

```
library(fields)
image.plot(lon, lat, tas, legend.width = 1.5, legend.shrink = 1, 
legend.mar = 1, cex.axis=2,cex.lab=2,legend.cex=1.8,legend.args=list(text="K", 
cex=2, side=3, line=0.5),las=1)
```

using above codes I get image plot but the font size of legend values is small. How to increase the font size of legend values?

[image: The link for sample image]

Comment: Isn't that what the `legend_cex = 1.8` argument is for?